# How to get previous values of flow variables when clicking on browser's back button?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

We're finally upgrading to Spring Webflow 2.4.x from 1.0.x and having problem with getting to real previous state (after clicking browser's back button). Abstract situation: form has 2 elements, 1st is shown when you open the page for the first time. Then you click on a button and 2nd element shows up. After clicking Back button, you can't get to the state, where only 1st element was shown.

2nd element shows up if there were no validation errors and flowScope variable is set to true. Right now it looks like true value of this variable becomes available to previous state, which is not expected behavior. It was working fine in Spring Webflow 1.0.x. What am I missing here?

Abstract code in flow:

```
<view-state id="searchForm" view="searchForm">
  ...
  <transition on="update1stElement" to="searchForm">
    ...
    <set name="flowScope.updatePerformed" value="true" />
  </transition>
  ...
</view-state>
```

Abstract code in jsp:

```
<form:form> <!-- org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag -->
  ...
  <1st element>
  <input type="submit" name="_eventId_update1stElement" id="_eventId_update1stElement" value="Update">
  <c:if test="${updatePerformed}">
    <2nd element>
  </c:if>
  ...
</form:form>
```

The same problem happens with formObjects of `org.springframework.webflow.action.FormAction`. They have flowScope too.

Comment: where and when are you storing your values

Comment: I updated question, added example and changed flashScope to flowScope, the problem is about flowScope variable.

Comment: so do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yeap, nothing changed and I didn't find the answer to the problem yet.

Comment: If you do not want the second element to show up on browser back button click, put the variable in view scope.

Comment: viewScope variable isn't available after transition, so with it I can't even get 2nd element to show up